# Can Flash AS3 FileReference access the size of a file on local disk before uploading to PHP?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, upload, flash-cs4

I want to be able to get the size of a file before uploading it to a PHP script using FileReference.

Can I get the file size before detecting bytesTotal during the upload process?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access that through the *"size"* property of the FileReference Object.
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html#size